# Why "DatetimeOffset" is coming up as "DateTime" in HotChocolate GraphQL Schema?

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I am using `Hot Chocolate` graphQL with .NET. In my Dto, I have one `DatetimeOffset` field but when I see the schema on UI, I see `DateTime`. I see the same even if I use `[GraphQLType(typeof(DateTimeOffset))]` or `[GraphQLType(typeof(DateTimeOffset?))]`.

How to fix this?

Code:

```
[GraphQLType(typeof(DateTimeOffset))]
public DateTimeOffset? EarliestPaymentDate { get; set; }
```

Schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL has no official scalar types for `DateTime`. Hot chocolate convert `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` to a [custom scalar type](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/scalars/#datetime-type)

Comment: Does this mean even if graphQl shows this as DateTime in schema, and if my BE has DateTimeOffSet, it will only accept that, not DateTime?

Comment: Updated my answer as I was wrong. Basically, I suspect that HotChocolate will accept `DateTime` while assuming they are UTC, or `DateTimeOffset` by using the specified offset.